# Привет, можете подсказать, как можно лаконизировать этот код?

Tags: c++, классы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Men
{
private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    float age;
public:
    void SetName(string name)   
    {
        this->name = name;
    }
    void SetSurname(string surname)
    {
        this->surname = surname;
    }
    void SetAge(int age)
    {
        this->age = age;
    }
    void printF()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << name << "\n" << "Surname: " << surname << "\n" << "Age: " << age << "\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    Men people;
    string name; 
    cout << "Name: "; 
    cin >> name;
    string surname; 
    cout << "Surname: "; 
    cin >> surname; 
    int age;
    cout << "Age: ";
    cin >> age;
    people.SetName(name); 
    people.SetSurname(surname);
    people.SetAge(age);
    people.printF();

}
```

Comment: Убрать все `set` и оставить только конструктор. И оператор вывода.

Comment: Нет ясного описания, что за класс и какой функциональностью должен обладать. И "лаконизировать **код**" - это что? Например, если `age` заменить на `a`, а `surname` на `s`, является  ли это "лаконизацией"? Каков критерий?

Comment: избавиться от лишних функция и переменных

Answer (score 6):

Например, так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Man
{
private:
    string name, surname;
    int age;
public:
    Man(const string& name, const string& surname, int age)
        :name(name),surname(surname),age(age){};

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Man& m)
    {
        return os << "Name: " << m.name << "\nSurname: "
            << m.surname << "\nAge: " << m.age << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Name: "; 
    cin >> name;
    string surname; 
    cout << "Surname: "; 
    cin >> surname; 
    int age;
    cout << "Age: ";
    cin >> age;

    Man people(name,surname,age);
    cout << people;
}
```

Comment: Конструктор копии и деструктор тоже не нужны.

Comment: Вот что тут надо, так это оператор ввода, а то создается куча ненужных переменных.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Чисто для того, чтобы показать, что это класс-значение. Естественно, компилятор их сгенерирует, но мы указываем явно, что нас это устраивает.

Comment: @user7860670 А вот тут я не уверен... Потому что оператор ввода должен взаимодействовать с пользователем, а использовать что-то, кроме потока ввода, я бы в операторе поостерегся. Скорее уж внешнюю функцию добавить для такого чтения ("фабрику", в определенном смысле).

Comment: Явный `=default` - это не просто плохой стиль, здесь это еще и влияет на поведение программы. Если ваш класс попробовать переместить, все поля вместо этого скопируются, потому что `=default` на копирующих операциях автоматически убирает перемещающие.

Comment: Параметры конструктора лучше принимать по значению, а потом мувать - не будет лишней копии.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Вы уже на целый ответ направили :) Дайте его, а то мне уже неудобно свой полностью переделывать.

Comment: Исправляйте смело, у меня в ответе конструктора вообще не будет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Типа https://ideone.com/6y6kHo? тоже вариант...

Comment: Ссылка не открывается. :( Выложите на pastebin или на https://gcc.godbolt.org/?

Comment: У вас, в отличие от @HolyBlackCat, как раз "лаконизация" без проектирования. Просто вряд ли кому-то потребуется класс только для вывода данных. Ваши бы ответы объединить ))

Answer (score 3):

Ну поехали.

- [`using namespace std;` - плохо](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2752075), как минимум потому что на первый взгляд перестает быть видно, где стандартные идентификаторы, а где ваши собственные.
- `Men` - опечатка. Это множественное число, в единственном должно быть `Man`. Или `Person`, чтобы не обвинили в сексизме, лол. Аналогично `people` - тоже множественное число, должно быть `person`.
- На `float age;` стоит добавить `= 0`. Вообще, все поля класса лучше всегда инициализировать/занулять в теле класса (и вообще всегда инициализировать любые переменные), чтобы не ловить труднообнаружимые ошибки на неинициализированных переменных.
- Недостает `std::move` в сеттерах: `this->name = std::move(name);`
- `printF`:

  - Забыт `const`: `void printF() const {...}`
  - Имя написано не в том стиле, что у других методов. Стоило выбрать `PrintF` или вообще `Print` (непонятно почему `F`).
  - Прибито гвоздями к `std::cout` - плохо, лучше принимать произвольный `std::ostream`.
  - Возможно стоит переименовать в `operator<<`, но тут как вам больше нравится.
  - Вообще, `std::ostream` теряет в популярности, и дело идет к тому, что `std::format` станет основным способом форматирования. Но пока его нормально не поддержали в libc++ (одной из трех популярных реализаций стандартной библиотеки С++), остается либо использоваться [библиотекой libfmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) (которая делает примерно то же самое), либо ждать. Плюс, непонятно, что тогда вместо `std::cin`.
- Странно, что из класса никак нельзя прочитать поля. Из-за этого им будет неудобно пользоваться.
- Если печать сделана методом класса, то я бы считывание тоже встроил в класс.
- Не хватает проверки на успешность считывания.
- Обычно я бы советовал убрать сеттеры (и геттеры) и просто сделать поля публичными, потому что ваши сеттеры все равно не делают ничего интересного.

  Но допустим в них можно было бы добавить какие-то проверки (на ум приходит проверка на `age >= 0`).

В итоге получается так:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class Person
{
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    float age = 0;

  public:
    Person() {} // Здесь ни на что не влияет, но наглядо.

    [[nodiscard]] const std::string &GetName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    void SetName(std::string name)   
    {
        this->name = std::move(name);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] const std::string &GetSurname() const
    {
        return surname;
    }
    void SetSurname(std::string surname)
    {
        this->surname = std::move(surname);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] int GetAge() const
    {
        return age;
    }
    void SetAge(int age)
    {
        assert(age >= 0); // Для примера.
        this->age = age;
    }
};

// Не член по аналогии с `operator>>`.
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &s, const Person &o)
{
    return s << "Name: " << o.GetName() << "\n"
                "Surname: " << o.GetSurname() << "\n"
                "Age: " << o.GetAge() << "\n";
}

// Не член, чтобы не мог напрямую выставлять приватные поля обходя проверки,
// и должен был использовать сеттеры.
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &s, Person &o)
{
    std::string name;
    s >> name;
    o.SetName(std::move(name));
    
    std::string surname;
    s >> surname;
    o.SetSurname(std::move(surname));

    int age = 0;
    s >> age;
    o.SetAge(age);

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    Person person;
    if (!(std::cin >> person))
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to read a person.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << person;
}
```

Здесь `[[nodiscard]]` - больше выпендреж, на таких простеньких классах я бы его не писал.

Если уверены, что в сеттерах проверки не нужны - их смело в мусор вместе с геттерами, а поля сделать публичными.

Comment: Если по отдельности устанавливаются все поля, при этом просто устанавливаются (без проверок и т.п.) — то это просто агрегат, тогда сеттеры вообще ни к чему (ой, вы это сами упомянули в конце...). Просто делаем `struct Man
{ string name, surname; int age;` и тогда никаких конструкторов, просто `Man people{name,surname,age};` (что я делал по не открывшейся у вас ссылке). Но я больше опять выскажусь против чтения через `>>` — как у вас оператор поймет, что именно и когда вводить при ручном вводе? Никаких указаний он не получает. А если вы их добавите — то почему именно через `cout`, например?

Comment: Вы скорее говорите не о лаконизации, а о правильном проектировании. Но оно зависит от цели, а цель ТС не указал.

Comment: Насчёт сеттеров есть мнение, что они нарушают принцип инкапсуляции. В ООП™ объект класса `Person` как абстракция человека должен принимать внешние изменения (например, прошедшее время) и уже сам в соответствии с этим изменять свой возраст, а не явно давать доступ к модификации внутренних полей.